# Flask: how to automate OpenAPI v3 documentation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, openapi

I need to document an API written in pure Flask 2 and I'm looking for what is a consolidated approach for doing this.
I found different viable solutions but being new to Python and Flask I'm not able to choose among them. The solutions I found are:

- https://github.com/marshmallow-code/apispec
- https://github.com/jmcarp/flask-apispec
- https://github.com/marshmallow-code/flask-smorest

In order to separate the different API endpoints I use the Flask blueprint.
The structure of a MWE is as follows:

[image: Project Structure]

I first defined two simple domain objects, **Author** and **Book**.

```
# author.py
class Author:
    def __init__(self, id: str, name: str):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

# book.py
class Book:
    def __init__(self, id: str, name: str):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
```

Next, I created a simple GET endpoint for both of them using two separate blueprints.

```
# author_apy.py
import json

from flask import Blueprint, Response

from domain.author import Author

author = Blueprint("author", __name__, url_prefix="/authors")


@author.get("/")
def authors():
    authors: list[Author] = []

    for i in range(10):
        author: Author = Author(str(i), "Author " + str(i))
        authors.append(author)

    authors_dicts = [author.__dict__ for author in authors]
    return Response(json.dumps(authors_dicts), mimetype="application/json")
```

and

```
# book_api.json
import json

from flask import Blueprint, Response

from domain.book import Book

book = Blueprint("book", __name__, url_prefix="/books")


@book.get("/")
def books():
    books: list[Book] = []

    for i in range(10):
        book: Book = Book(str(i), "Book " + str(i))
        books.append(book)

    books_dicts = [book.__dict__ for book in books]
    return Response(json.dumps(books_dicts), mimetype="application/json")
```

In the end I simply registered both the blueprints under the Flask app.

```
# app.py
from flask import Flask
from api.author.author_api import author
from api.book.book_api import book

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(author, url_prefix="/authors")
app.register_blueprint(book, url_prefix="/books")


@app.get('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Flask - OpenAPI'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The whole source code is also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/MaurizioCasciano/flask-openapi).

Considering this minimal working example, I'd like to know what is the quickest way to automate the generation of an OpenAPI v3 yaml/JSON file, e.g. exposed on a /api-doc.yaml endpoint.

PS: this is my first API using Python and Flask. I am trying to reproduce what I'm able to do with [Spring-Boot](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot) and [SpringDoc](https://springdoc.org/)

Comment: what is the main question/problem?

Comment: I need to automatically generate an OpenAPI v3 specification for the Flask API endpoints defined in different blueprints. The objects/schemas are not defined using any convention/framework, but a simple json.dumps is used for returning the values in the Response.

Comment: I know its a bit late, but can check this one https://pypi.org/project/flask-toolkits/

Comment: [flask_openapi3](https://luolingchun.github.io/flask-openapi3/) and [flask-restx](https://flask-restx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) exist as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encourage you to switch your project to FastAPI, it isn't much different or more difficult than Flask.

[FastAPI docs about generating OpenAPI schema](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/first-steps/?h=openapi#check-the-openapijson)

It will not only allow you to generate OpenAPI docs / specification easily. It is also asynchronous, much faster and modern.

See also [FastAPI Alternatives, Inspiration and Comparisons](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/alternatives/) to read about differences.

Especially this citation from link above should explain why doing what you try to do may not be the best idea:

> Flask REST frameworks
>
> There are several Flask REST frameworks, but after investing the time
> and work into investigating them, I found that many are discontinued
> or abandoned, with several standing issues that made them unfit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I gave it a try and it looks very interesting.
I'll consider migrating the existing project from Flask to FastAPI if, as I fear, there
will be no other quick solution provided.

Comment: @1Z10 migrating will be easy peasy, you don't need to be afraid of it ;)

Comment: Instead of the info about comparisons to other frameworks, what would make this a better answer would be to show an actual example: at least one of the routes from the OP's question ported for FastAPI + the auto-generated FastAPI docs (screenshot of how it would look like). While the comparison to Flask is interesting, that was not the question.

Comment: Flask-Smorest (using apispec) can do the same for Flask, and is actively maintained by the Marshmallow team.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'd really appreciate to see a simple example applied to my MWE if you can provide it.

Comment: @GinoMempin I agree, I decided no to do it because of limited time. However OP did it in separate answer :)

Comment: I disagree - FastAPI requires you to move to async, which means different PG driver, different part of SQLAlchemy, additional complications for pytest - a whole new world of pain.  Please do not sugar-coat this.

Comment: @odigity FastAPI doesn't require you to use async at all. However it has other pain points. Nowadays I prefer litestar framework: https://github.com/litestar-org/litestar

Answer (score 8):

Following the suggestion of migrating from Flask to FastAPI I gave it a try and rewrote the [Flask-Example](https://github.com/MaurizioCasciano/Flask-OpenAPI) of the question. The source code is also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/MaurizioCasciano/FastAPI-OpenAPI).

The structure of the project is almost identical, with some additional features available(e.g. the CORS Middleware):
[image]

The models of the domain are slightly different and extend the [BaseModel](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/) from [Pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/).

```
# author.py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Author(BaseModel):
    id: str
    name: str
```

and

```
# book.py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Book(BaseModel):
    id: str
    name: str
```

With FastAPI the equivalent of the **Flask Blueprint** is the **APIRouter**.
Below are the two controllers for the authors

```
# author_api.py
from fastapi import APIRouter

from domain.author import Author

router = APIRouter()


@router.get("/", tags=["Authors"], response_model=list[Author])
def get_authors() -> list[Author]:
    authors: list[Author] = []

    for i in range(10):
        authors.append(Author(id="Author-" + str(i), name="Author-Name-" + str(i)))

    return authors
```

and the books

```
# book_api.py
from fastapi import APIRouter

from domain.book import Book

router = APIRouter()


@router.get("/", tags=["Books"], response_model=list[Book])
def get_books() -> list[Book]:
    books: list[Book] = []

    for i in range(10):
        books.append(Book(id="Book-" + str(i), name="Book-Name-" + str(i)))

    return books
```

It is important to note that the response model of the API endpoints is defined using Python types thanks to Pydantic. These object types are then converted into JSON schemas for the OpenAPI documentation.

In the end I simply registered/included the APIRouters under the FastAPI object and added a configuration for CORS.

```
# app.py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

from domain.info import Info
from api.author.author_api import router as authors_router
from api.book.book_api import router as books_router

app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(authors_router, prefix="/authors")
app.include_router(books_router, prefix="/books")

app.add_middleware(CORSMiddleware,
                   allow_credentials=True,
                   allow_origins=["*"],
                   allow_methods=["*"],
                   allow_headers=["*"],
                   )


@app.get("/", response_model=Info)
def info() -> Info:
    info = Info(info="FastAPI - OpenAPI")
    return info
```

The generated OpenAPI documentation is accessible at the endpoint `/openapi.json` while the UI (aka Swagger UI, Redoc) is accessible at `/docs`

[image]

and `/redoc`

[image]

To conclued, this is the automatically generated OpenAPI v3 documentation in JSON format, which can be used to easily generate an API client for other languages (e.g. using the [OpenAPI-Generator tools](https://openapi-generator.tech/)).

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.2",
  "info": {
    "title": "FastAPI",
    "version": "0.1.0"
  },
  "paths": {
    "/authors/": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Authors"
        ],
        "summary": "Get Authors",
        "operationId": "get_authors_authors__get",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful Response",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "title": "Response Get Authors Authors  Get",
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Author"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/books/": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Books"
        ],
        "summary": "Get Books",
        "operationId": "get_books_books__get",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful Response",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "title": "Response Get Books Books  Get",
                  "type": "array",
                  "items": {
                    "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Book"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "/": {
      "get": {
        "summary": "Info",
        "operationId": "info__get",
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "Successful Response",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Info"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "Author": {
        "title": "Author",
        "required": [
          "id",
          "name"
        ],
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "title": "Id",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "name": {
            "title": "Name",
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "Book": {
        "title": "Book",
        "required": [
          "id",
          "name"
        ],
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "title": "Id",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "name": {
            "title": "Name",
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "Info": {
        "title": "Info",
        "required": [
          "info"
        ],
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "info": {
            "title": "Info",
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In order to start the application we also need an ASGI server for production, such as  [Uvicorn](https://www.uvicorn.org/) or [Hypercorn](https://gitlab.com/pgjones/hypercorn).
I used Uvicorn and the app is started using the command below:

```
uvicorn app:app --reload
```

It is then available on the port *8000* of your machine.

Comment: thanks for documenting the process, great post!

Comment: plus one for generator talk. automating openapi snippets for apidoc code should also be checked out

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to stick with Flask, `swagger-gen` is a library that can generate full-featured specs with pretty low implementation overhead.

```py
from swagger_gen.lib.wrappers import swagger_metadata
from swagger_gen.lib.security import BearerAuth
from swagger_gen.swagger import Swagger
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/api/hello/say', methods=['GET'])
@swagger_metadata(
    summary='Sample endpoint',
    description='This is a sample endpoint')
def test():
    return {'message': 'hello world!'}


swagger = Swagger(
    app=app,
    title='app')

swagger.configure()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port='5000')
```

Full disclosure: I'm the author.

Comment: For some reason, your lib was very hard to find.  Here it is for anyone searching: https://github.com/danleonard-nj/swagger-gen

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib.metadata'
getting this error with swagger-gen

Comment: @UpasanaMittal importlib.metadata was introduced in Python 3.8, so you'll need that version or above.  I figured it was safe to use since that release is about 3 years old :)

Comment: @aleith `pip install swagger-gen` should do it.